# Graphical difftool for Linux that supports word wrap/line break

Tags: ubuntu, diff, meld, kdiff3

Using [Ubuntu 20.04](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Ubuntu_20.04_LTS_(Focal_Fossa)) (Focal Fossa) I would like to use a graphical diff tool (like [Meld](http://meldmerge.org/), [KDiff3](http://kdiff3.sourceforge.net/), [Kompare](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kompare), etc.) that supports automatic line breaks. What I mean by that is that I would like to see the entire text in the graphical window that's available to me, without the need of scrolling horizontally, as this is incredibly painful when using text (scientific papers) with very long lines (i.e., long paragraphs).

I've checked all "top X diff tools" webpages and tried more than 10 graphical diff tools. *None* of them supports automatic word wraps/line breaks (or however they are called). In all of them, long lines are just endlessly long lines.

Fun fact: I **know** that Meld did support this at some point, but apparently it does not any more. For some extremely weird reason, they've just removed this feature.

To be more precise, KDiff3 actually does support this, but it seems that it does not allow to *edit* the text being displayed, which is another extremely essential feature since diff tools get "confused" very easily, so one needs to constantly do some minor alterations to the text so that the differ keeps recognizing similarities.

So, what tool can be recommend? It's driving me crazy that I can't use a differ any more...

Comment: this should be on [softwarerecs.se]

Comment: Interesting, I did not even know that... Though I'm not sure whether a post can be moved...

Comment: you can just ask a new question. Moving is possible but tricky

Comment: Hmkay, I guess I will, then. Do you recommend to delete this one? I was never in the wrong forum before! :) Not that I know of, at least...

Answer (score 4):

The [Meld](http://meldmerge.org/) utility has the option.

In the menu bar, click on *Meld* → *Preferences* → *Editor* → *Enable text wrapping*.

I can confirm it's available as of the 3.20.2 release.

Comment: THANK YOU !!! I was indeed still facing that problem! :) Though since Meld was always my favorite editor of all time, I strongly assume that the version I used on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS some 'fixed' Meld version was installed in which that feature didn't exist anymore... Though I don't know, since I recently upgraded to Ubuntu 21.04 (which runs Meld 3.20.3). Would you mind telling me your OS? It doesn't really matter anymore, I'm just curious whether I indeed did not find that option (under Meld, unknown version, running Ubuntu 20.04) or whether they indeed removed it temporarily...

Comment: The option's called "Enable text wrapping" in 3.20.2 so if one is used to look for "Word wrap" it is easy to miss it on a quick scan of the options.

Answer (score 2):

One possible answer, though that is technically not what I'm looking for since it's not a GUI (though I only said "graphical", which it is, I did technically not restrict to GUI -- although I meant that) is `icdiff`. It puts the two texts onto the terminal, but highlights differences in color (with the demanded line wrap).

It was recommended in [another Stack Overflow post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/537418/how-to-make-text-wrap-with-diff-y), which you should probably vote on (question + answer) if you find this helpful.

Comment: Works to some degree, but if lines on the right are longer than those on the left, just a newline is inserted so that the end of the right-hand line appears on the left. Very confusing.